# Magento search and Multiple attribute sets

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I've a question.
I am working on a Magento website for selling only two types of products:  condoms & lubes. 
Both will there own page, and both pages will have search option.
I created 2 attribute sets, 1 for each type of product. 
Now, when user is on **Condom** page or search from Condom page, only condom type products should be displayed.

Please help me with this. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two different store-views and relate your products to store-view then you can achieve this. You can create different websites as well

Comment: actually I can not create store view for this, because I am already using store views for multi lingual option.

Comment: well you certainly can create those as your dimensions require it so you create as many different multilingual versions as well. Or you can create two different websites with different store-views

Comment: I have three store view English, French, German.
now suppose I create 2 websites. I have to create 3 store views for each website? 

how can I access these website from the front end?

Comment: I created a new website with code **lubes**. created a new store (lube store) for this website and added a new store view English with code **en** to website. but when I try to access it using **http://HOST/magento/lubes** or **http://HOST/magento/index.php/lubes** i get 404. 
is there anything I need to change in config or files?

Comment: you should enable store codes in urls or set the code in index.php

Comment: Thank you @anton-s  thanks for the information. but, how to set this in index.php? 
and if I create two  different store front and websites, should my site user be able to see items in their cart when they go to different site?
i.e. : 
I added a product from condom store to my cart, went to Lubes store and added another. will I be able to see all products to my cart? when I checkout, will I be able to place the order at once...

Comment: there's no excuse for you to actually learn how magento handles those things as the answers are right in admin page settings if you care to explore the sections and test them out

Comment: Thank you for all you help :) .  I found another way for this, because having two website for the purpose I wanted to fulfill was way too much. I did some R&D on multi-site multi-store front, and found that it is not going to solve my problem. so, I created 2 home page by copying index.php as home.php and adding some **if...else** there and adding **request_uri** check on other pages. 

I am still struggling with displaying only specific product on specific page :(

Answer (score 0):

@anton-s soulution helped me a lot, and after his solutions and suggestions, I did couple of tests and r&d. 
What needed was relatively simple than what I was asking for, sorry for that. I don't know if I did right thing, but, I created two home pages : **index.php** and **home.php** because I needed to display different forms on these two pages, and added some checks such as :

```
$_product->getAttributeSetId();
```

thank you everyone for your suggestions :)